# How to reset itertools count between pytests?

Tags: python, pytest, python-itertools

I am creating objects with an index value from itertools.count()

```
class Object:
    new_index = itertools.count()
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.index = next(self.new_index)
```

I then have multiple pytest tests in the one file.
The first test runs fine returning 0,1,2 as the index of my 3 objects, but the subsequent tests keep counting so test 2 is 3,4,5 and so on.
Is there a way to reset this value between tests so that it always returns 0,1,2

Comment: You need to reorganise your code (or test) so that `new_index` is created anew for each test.

Comment: if you know how to create/use fixtures then you should make this a fixture

Comment: Can you share some of your pytest code in the question, so it's possible to look at the overall setup to answer this?

Comment: so you mean for the fourth test the count should be 0 again?

Answer (score 1):

Mutable global state makes it hard to write independent unit tests. Your code will be more testable if you redesign it so that the mutable state is encapsulated in some object, instead of being global. I would have an `ObjectFactory` class which encapsulates the auto-incrementing counter:

```py
import itertools

class Object:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index

class ObjectFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = itertools.count()
    def create(self):
        index = next(self.counter)
        return Object(index)
```

Then your application and unit test class should create objects by first creating a factory; the unit test class can create this factory in a [`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) method to avoid code duplication across multiple tests.

Answer (score 0):

The `itertools.count` iterator cannot be reset, I think. However, the following code would accomplish your goal of restarting counting objects. The test sequence is based on the sort order of the test method names:

```
import unittest
import itertools

class MyObject:
    new_index = itertools.count()
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.index = next(self.new_index)


class TestItertoolsMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        obj = MyObject()
        print(obj.index, end=' ')
        self.assertEqual(obj.index, 0, "Miss")
    def test_b(self):
        MyObject.new_index = itertools.count()
        obj = MyObject()
        print(obj.index, end=' ')
        self.assertEqual(obj.index, 0, "Miss")
    def test_c(self):
        obj = MyObject()
        print(obj.index, end=' ')
        self.assertEqual(obj.index, 1, "Miss")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output

```
...0 0 1 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.003s

OK
```